# Video.js on Safari (IOS)

Tags: ios, safari, mp4, video.js, video-player

I have an issue with the Video.js player on Safari on iOS devices. When I try to play the video, it starts, as indicated by the timeline. However, neither audio nor video is played. After about 10 seconds, the video automatically restarts, and only then does sound and video start playing from the beginning. It's quite perplexing. I've also experimented with different preload options. In all other browsers (like Safari on Mac), playback works without problems. I'm at a loss and grateful for any advice!

HTML:

```
<div class="outer-container-sr">
            <div class="video-container-sr">
                <video id="my-video" class="video-js vjs-21-9" controls preload="auto" playsinline data-setup="{}"
                    poster="https://www.sontak.de/Bilder/Lumixers_breit.jpg">
                    <source src="showreel_2023_V7.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    <!-- Fügen Sie hier alternative Quellen für das Video ein, z.B. WebM oder Ogg -->
                    Dein Browser unterstützt keine Videos.
                </video>
            </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            var video = videojs('my-video', {
                controlBar: {
                    volumePanel: false,
                    pictureInPictureToggle: false
                }
            });
        });
```

CSS:

```
.outer-container-sr {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index: 5;
}

.video-container-sr {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 42.85%;
    /* 21:9 aspect ratio (100 / 21.85) */
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.video-container-sr .video-js {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.vjs-icon-placeholder:before {
    color: white;
    line-height: 150%;
}



/* Playkasten */

.video-container-sr .vjs-big-play-button {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 16px;
    left: 60px;
    height: 3rem;
    top: initial;
    /* Zurücksetzen der vorherigen Transformationsregel */
    background-color: #2F54E6;
    opacity: 0.75;
    /* Wert zwischen 0 und 1 für die Deckkraft */
    border: 0.05em solid #fff;
}

/* Overlay */

.video-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
    /* Hinzugefügte Übergangsanimation */
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 1;
    /* Anfangs sichtbar */
}

.video-container-sr.vjs-has-started .video-overlay {
    opacity: 0;
    /* Auf 0 setzen, wenn das Video gestartet wurde */
}

.video-title {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: white;
}

/* ... Ihr bisheriges CSS ... */



@media (max-width: 40rem) {

    .video-container-sr .vjs-big-play-button {

        width: 4rem;
        height: 2.5rem;

    }

    .vjs-icon-play,
    .video-js .vjs-play-control .vjs-icon-placeholder,
    .video-js .vjs-big-play-button .vjs-icon-placeholder:before {
        font-family: VideoJS;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        line-height: 125%;
    }

    .vjs-icon-placeholder:before {
        color: white;
        line-height: 150%;
    }

    .video-container-sr .vjs-big-play-button {
        margin-top: initial;
        margin-left: initial;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width: 4rem;
        height: 2.5rem;
        background-color: #2F54E6;
        opacity: 0.75;
        border: 0.05em solid #fff;


    }

}
```

The Website is hosted on: [[redesign.sontak.de]](https://redesign.sontak.de)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your HTML / JS / CSS code.

Your MP4 video has its metadata at the back of the file. It won't play without metadata, so users must first await for the full 155mb to download before seeing a picture.

**Solution**:
Use a tool to move it to the front of file. Use FFmpeg if you know it... 
Or Google search for such tools (maybe even some  online editor can do it).

Search for keywords : `MP4 move metadata atom to front moov` or `MP4 fast start`.

This is because MP4 puts data in sections called "atom" (or "box" by others). 
 The metadata atom itself is called `moov`. This is resolution / FPS / duration etc.
The audio/video bytes go into the section `mdat` (media data).